# What does "~" do in python besides being a bitwise negation op?

Tags: python

I've seen it being used in a couple of projects in conjunction with `yield` and Deferred like so: `yield ~ some_fun()`. Sometimes it works without the `~` bit, sometimes it doesn't. Can't figure out what it actually does, help.

Comment: A bit vague. Why not give *examples* of when it works without `~` and when it doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the class being 'inverted' has a `__invert__(self)` method, if so, that's overriding the tilde operator.